# How to simulate a AJAX call (XHR) with python and mechanize

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, web-scraping, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am working on a project that does online homework automatically.
I am able to login, finding exercises and even filling the form using mechanize.
I discovered that the submit button trigger a javascript function and I searched for the solution. A lot of answers consist of 'simulating the XHR'. But none of them talked about the details.
I don't know if this screen cap helps.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g83g.png
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to evaluate javascript, I'd recommend using Selenium. It will open a browser which you can then send text to it from python.

First, install Selenium: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Then download the chrome driver from here: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Put the binary in the same folder as the python script you're writing. (Or add it to the path or whatever, more information here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

Afterwards the following example should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "Google" in driver.title
driver.close()
```

More information [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
(The example was also from there)

Answer (score 0):

A xhr is the same as a regular request. Make it the same way and then deal with the response.

Comment: resp = br.open(clockurl)
resp.readlines() # ['                                                                                                                                                                   \n', '\n', '\n']
I could only receive first 3 states of response. Actual response which is in 4th state, couldn't get able to get in response. How to get 4th state actual response?